# Dropdown in dataview

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5, dataview

In my GridView, I have the following columns:

```
<Columns>  
    <asp:BoundField DataField="report_type" HeaderText="Report Type"   
        SortExpression="report_type" />  

    <asp:BoundField DataField="progress" HeaderText="Progress"   
        SortExpression="progress" />  

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="..">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataValueField="progress">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Incomplete</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Complete</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField> 
</Columns>
```

The progress column is just there for demo purposes which will eventually be removed.  How do I get the value of the progress to select the correct itemlist in the dropdown?

So if the value of `progress` is `1`, the dropdown should have `Complete` selected.  If the value of the `progress` is `0`, the dropdown should have `Incomplete` selected.

Comment: Is it DataView or DetailView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a OnRowDataBound attribute to the gridview in the .aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="id" OnRowDataBound="GridViewRowEventHandler">
```

Replace

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Progress" HeaderText="Progress"   
    SortExpression="progress" />
```

with

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>             
       <asp:Label ID="progress_Flags" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Progress").ToString()%>'/>
  </ItemTemplate>                    
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void GridViewRowEventHandler(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       Label flag = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("progress_Flags");
       DropDownList myDropDown = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        if (flag.Text == "1")
        {
            myDropDown.SelectedValue = "1";
        }
    //add more conditions here..

    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `RowDataBound` event you can use `e.Row.FindControl`

```
protected void GridView_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

   GridViewRow row = e.Row;
   DataRowView dr = row.DataItem as DataRowView;
   // now find the control in the row by control ID
   DropDownList myDropDown = row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
}
```